# Java regex pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to match the following string pattern for my code. the string value is fixed as below:

630512-07-5847

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{6,6})-(\\d{2,2})-(\\d{4,4})");
```

I've tried the code above, however, when it has more number such as "630512312-07-5847" , it still return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
^\\d{6}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$
```

This will make sure the if the match begins and end with the entire string,

so

- 630512-07-5847 - OK
- 630512-07-58472 - NOT OK
- 1630512-07-5847 - NOT OK

Comment: Thank you, your method works, however, when i use Matcher.find() twice, it return me two different result.

Comment: for example :
System.out.println( m.find() ) ;
return m.find();

Comment: The first `find` will return `true`, the second one will return `false`

Comment: yes, i am wondering why this would happened, since I've pass the pattern and value to matcher

Comment: @hiboss The docs explains the why. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()

Comment: This is the correct behaviour as finding the first match, there are not matches left

Comment: I see, thank you for the document and explanation, have a nice day :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you tried actually?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("630512312-07-5847".matches("(\\d{6,6})-(\\d{2,2})-(\\d{4,4})"));
    }
}
```

the result is false, bad question

Comment: you answer works good too. I am using the Pattern and Matcher library for my string matching though. didn't know such method works without the library